# Dicomize ECG Raw Signal Data

Tags: c#, signal-processing, dicom, clearcanvas

I have dicomized raw signal data by using clear canvas library.(ecg voltage values) But,I have faced a problem about seperating the ecg channels. When I display the dicomized data on PACS system all the channels append each other and are visualized as single waveform. (However I put 12 into number of waveform channels variable and therefore there must be 12 different seperate channels.)

I have put correct values into **"Number Of Waveform Samples"** and **"Number Of Waveform Channels"** variables, but there must be something wrong.

How can I seperate this single ecg signal into multiple channels according to channel information?

This is a simple file I try to visualize on pacs server.

http://www.ikincidoktor.com/tmp/I00000006679.dcm

It has two channels but channels append each other and visualized on pacs.

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t see any issue in the DICOM attribute encoding, you just need to verify the waveform data matches the value in the DICOM attributes. Note that the waveform data values are expected to have interleaved encoding, incrementing by channel and then by sample (i.e., C1S1, C2S1, C3S1, … CnS1, C1S2, C2S2,C3S2, … CnSm), with no padding or explicit delimitation between successive samples. Cx denotes the channel defined in the Channel Definition Sequence ITEM in item number x.

Answer (score 1):

According to your DICOM file, dataset only has two waveform channels. [image]

Comment: Yes you are right, but in my pacs server it displays these two channels as one. I digitized 2 channels and dicomized them but when I try to visualize them, my pacs server visualized them together.

Comment: Also in your image two channels look same. The problem is there are two different channels in dcm file.

Comment: I am seeing the same graph for both the channels in other 3rd party ECG viewer. Perhaps your source waveform data has the issue.

Comment: Actually the problem is seeing same graph for both channels. There must be two different graph for two channels. The graph you have seen is the combination of two different graph. I need to split the waveform graph.

Comment: I put all the voltage values in one tag and created two channel sequences for two channels. I expect to see two different signal when visiualizing but I saw two same signal.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It is because of the voltage order of multiple ecg signals. The order must be (C1V1 C2V1 C3V1 ...)